# How to extract desired sections from a JSON string

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to know how to clean up my data to better understand it so that I can know how to sift through the data more easily. So far I have been able to download a public google spreadsheets doc and then convert that into a csv file. But when I print the data it is quite messy and hard to understand. The data came from a website, so when I go to google developer mode I can see how it is neatly organized.

Like this:
[Website data on inspect page mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRMka.png)

But actually seeing it as I print into in Jupyter notebooks it looks messy like this:

> b'/*O_o*/\ngoogle.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0output=csv","status":"ok","sig":"1241529276","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Entity","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"Week","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"C","label":"Day","type":"date","pattern":"yyyy-mm-dd"},{"id":"D","label":"Flights
> 2019
> (Reference)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"E","label":"Flights","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"F","label":"%
> vs 2019
> (Daily)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"G","label":"Flights
> (7-day moving
> average)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"H","label":"% vs
> 2019 (7-day Moving
> Average)","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"I","label":"Day
> 2019","type":"date","pattern":"yyyy-mm-dd"},{"id":"J","label":"Day
> Previous
> Year","type":"date","pattern":"yyyy-mm-dd"},{"id":"K","label":"Flights
> Previous
> Year","type":"number","pattern":"General"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,1)","f":"2020-09-01"},{"v":129.0,"f":"129"},{"v":64.0,"f":"64"},{"v":-0.503875968992248,"f":"-0,503875969"},{"v":71.5714285714286,"f":"71,57142857"},{"v":-0.291371994342291,"f":"-0,2913719943"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,3)","f":"2019-09-03"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,3)","f":"2019-09-03"},{"v":129.0,"f":"129"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,2)","f":"2020-09-02"},{"v":92.0,"f":"92"},{"v":59.0,"f":"59"},{"v":-0.358695652173913,"f":"-0,3586956522"},{"v":70.0,"f":"70"},{"v":-0.300998573466476,"f":"-0,3009985735"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,4)","f":"2019-09-04"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,4)","f":"2019-09-04"},{"v":92.0,"f":"92"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,3)","f":"2020-09-03"},{"v":96.0,"f":"96"},{"v":67.0,"f":"67"},{"v":-0.302083333333333,"f":"-0,3020833333"},

Is there a Panda way to keep this data up?

Essentially what I am trying to do is extract three variables from the data: country, date, and a number.

Here it can be seen how the code starts out with the title, "rows":

[Code in Jupyter showing how the code starts out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3tcd.png)

Essentially it gives a country, date, then a bunch of associated numbers.

What I want to get is the country name, a specific date, and a specific number.

For example, here is an example section, this sequence is repeated throughout the data:

> {"c":[{"v":"Albania"},{"v":36.0,"f":"36"},{"v":"Date(2020,8,1)","f":"2020-09-01"},{"v":129.0,"f":"129"},{"v":64.0,"f":"64"},{"v":-0.503875968992248,"f":"-0,503875969"},{"v":71.5714285714286,"f":"71,57142857"},{"v":-0.291371994342291,"f":"-0,2913719943"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,3)","f":"2019-09-03"},{"v":"Date(2019,8,3)","f":"2019-09-03"},{"v":129.0,"f":"129"}]},

of this section of the data I only want to get out the word Country name: Albania, the date "2020-09-01", and the number -0.5038

Here is the code I used to grab the google spreadsheet data and save it as a csv:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 

r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GJ6CvZ_mgtjdrUyo3h2dU3YvWOahbYvPHpGLgovyhtI/gviz/tq?usp=sharing&tqx=reqId%3A0output=csv')

data = r.content

print(data)
```

Please any and all advice would be amazing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you arrived at this csv file, but the easiest way would be to get the json directly with requests, load it as a dict and process it. Nonetheless a solution for the current file would be:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import json

r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GJ6CvZ_mgtjdrUyo3h2dU3YvWOahbYvPHpGLgovyhtI/gviz/tq?usp=sharing&tqx=reqId%3A0output=jspn')

data = r.content
data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8').split("(", 1)[1].rsplit(")", 1)[0]) # clean up the string so only the json data is left
d = [[i['c'][0]['v'], i['c'][2]['f'], i['c'][5]['v']] for i in data['table']['rows']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['country', 'date', 'number'])
```

```
Output:
|    | country   | date       |        number |
|---:|:----------|:-----------|--------------:|
|  0 | Albania   | 2020-09-01 |     -0.503876 |
|  1 | Albania   | 2020-09-02 |     -0.358696 |
|  2 | Albania   | 2020-09-03 |     -0.302083 |
|  3 | Albania   | 2020-09-04 |     -0.135922 |
|  4 | Albania   | 2020-09-05 |     -0.43617  |
```

Comment: You can also slice `data` to `data = json.loads(data[47:-2])`

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen, Thank you! is there any sort of way to have it specifically pull out a countries name and then do grab its specific date and number? I need to extract out specific countries and their associated data points.

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen, also here is the website I am scraping the data from: https://www.eurocontrol.int/Economics/DailyTrafficVariation-States.html. I go to inspect the page and go into the XHR and see where the GET requests are coming from. Not sure how to json it. Would love to know how to.

Comment: No now I see that the site itself loads it in this format from a google spreadsheet, so you can settle for my code. Filtering by country can be easily done in pandas: `df[df['country'] == 'France']`

Comment: @RJ Adriaanse, I am sorry for my question I now see that pandas prints only the first 5. This is an amazing answer thank you so much

Comment: @JohnReese23487 to show more rows set display options at the top of your code `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 400)` & `pd.set_option('display.min_rows', 40)` as an example. Change the numbers as needed.